# concatenation of address strings in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i am trying to concatenate an address whose 1 part is being fetched at line 15 of the following code and another part from line 19.. i want to add the address separator "\" symbol in between both .. but i am not able to due to some error.. can anyone help me in this.. thank you..:) 
here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using System.Linq; 
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace freshtry 
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int count = 0;
            string[] filepath= Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\project\Benten_lat\BentenPj_000_20141124_final\Testing\DPCPlus\output\msvs", "*.wav");
            string folder1 = @"D:\project\Benten_lat\BentenPj_000_20141124_final\Testing\DPCPlus\output\msvs";
            foreach(string file in filepath)
            {
                //string addr = "\";
                string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                string filename1 = folder1 + "\" + filename;
                Console.WriteLine(filename1);
                //string.Concat(folder1,"\");
                count++;
            }
            //Console.WriteLine(count);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }  
    }    
}
```

and one more thing i don't want to add any additional directories which don't work with .net 2.0.:)

Comment: could  you  provide an example of output please ?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify `some error`.

Comment: Use Path.Combine instead of Path concatenation string filename1 = folder1 + "\" + filename;

Comment: Better title: Build a path from several parts

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code here:

```
string filename1 = folder1 + "\" + filename;
```

is invalid, as `\` is an escape character. You can either escape the backslash, using `\\`, or use the `@` symbol to prevent escaping: `@"\"`.

You could also look at the `Path.Combine()` method, which is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: thanks for the answer.. it is working successfully..:)

Answer (score 1):

simple answer: Use double backslash

```
string filename1 = folder1 + "\\" + filename;
```

Better answer: Use

```
string filename1 = Path.Combine(folder1, filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like

```
 string filename1 = folder1 + "\\" + filename;
```

Or

```
string filename1 = string.Concat(folder1, "\\", filename);
```